# Android Studio designer preview different to phone

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, preview

I'm new to android studio and developing on the android platform. I'm having a problem where the Android Studio designer preview doesn't show exactly what is on my phone. It shows an extra Toolbar widget at the top of the screen. I've had a look in the XML file for the activity and cannot find where it is coming from. It would be much appreciated if one of you could help.

Designer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKyoC.jpg

Phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g45Vc.jpg

This is a snippet from the XML file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.tomnulty.helloworld.SecondActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And this is a snippet from the AndroidManifest file:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/hello_world"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SECOND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: What theme are you using? In the preview pane of AS you'll find the selected theme on the top

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi The first picture is the preview of the Activity in Android Studio. The second picture is a screenshot of the activity from my phone. On the preview I have an extra toolbar widget with "Hello World" in it. It should not be there, although I cannot find where it is created in the XML files.

Comment: @Pztar I am using "AppTheme". Is this wrong?

Comment: No, it isn't necessarily wrong. Go into your `styles.xml` and under the `AppTheme` style set the parent as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: I see you're using at least 3 themes... might it be that some one conflicts with another one?

Comment: It works @Pztar! Thanks a lot! :) I didn't realise that the preview window had its own theme. I thought if the theme within the Manifest file is declared then it would change. Feel free to add the answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi It was as Pztar explained. I hadn't updated the theme in my styles file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pztar said, "Go into your `styles.xml` and under the `AppTheme` style set the parent as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`"

Although my theme was set when I declared the activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`, this did not change the preview. This had to be done by changing the theme in the UI of Android Studio or the `styles.xml` file.

Styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That's because in your manifest you set the activity theme as `AppTheme.NoActionBar` and your Preview had `AppTheme` by default it includes an `ActionBar/ToolBar` so when you specify `.NoActionBar` it takes it away. You can now set your manifest to `AppTheme` and it will show it without the bar since you overrode the parent value.

Answer (score 0):

Using Android Studio 3.0 stable, you can change to your custom theme in the preview panel. **To remind, the design time is not the same to the runtime if your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml does not implement the same one.**
[image: Change App Theme]